# how to restore reviews sql from Magento

Tags: magento

So by mistake I erased all my reviews from our Magento store. The interesting thing is that when I logged in PhpMyAdmin, I can still see the review_detail table where all my reviews are, so I guess it was not deleted from database?

Now the question is, how do I get those reviews from database to show up on the site? Do I erase the review_detail database and import it again?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more detail on how you accidentally erase it (using sql, changes to magento xml..etc)?

Comment: I accidentally erased it through Admin area. Was working on erasing some spam reviews and hit the "check all" button and all went gone. After I went to MyPhp and can see they are still there under review_detail table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento reviews are stores across three different database tables.

The `review` table is the main table that keeps track of each review object and links it to the object (i.e. product) its reviewing. If you don't have an entry in there, you don't have a review.

The `review_detail` table is the table that actually contains the review information.

Finally, the `review_store` table keeps track of which reviews belong in each Magento store instances. (store meaning Magento "store" objects in the same system)

My guess is your delete operation got though the `review` table, but not the others. If this is the case your data (without backups) is gone. If there's still data there then you've got a different, more subtle issue going on, and I'm not sure that sort of data restoration is the sort of thing an expert could walk a non-expert through.

Comment: Thank you Alan. Your answer is correct. I was able to link the review_detail table to review table manually, one by one. From review_table I could get review_id and entity_pk_value which I then entered them manually at review table. The only thing missing is the date when reviews were written so had not choice but to check when the order for such product was place by such customer and estimate customer submited review 20 days after receiving order. Luckily is only 97 reviews I have to go through :)

Comment: just to clarify the entity_pk_value you get from rating_option_vote table and not from review_table

Comment: part of review data is rating, which is stored in rating_option tables

Answer (score 1):

Little script based on Alan's and Giri06's answers to restore your disapeared reviews.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('./app/etc/local.xml', NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$db['host'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host;
$db['name'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->dbname;
$db['user'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->username;
$db['pass'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->password;
$pref = $xml->global->resources->db->table_prefix;
mysql_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass']) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db['name']) or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("select `entity_pk_value`,`review_id` from `{$pref}rating_option_vote`") or die(mysql_error());
for ($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($result);$i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $exists = mysql_query("select `entity_pk_value`,`review_id` from `{$pref}review` where `review_id`=".$row['review_id']) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_num_rows($exists)) {
        $query = "insert into `{$pref}review`(`entity_pk_value`,`review_id`,`entity_id`,`status_id`,`created_at`) values({$row['entity_pk_value']},{$row['review_id']},1,1,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2013-01-01 01:00:00')+floor(rand()*31536000)))";
        echo "Inserting {$row['review_id']}<br>";
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Date or reviews is randomly generated somewhere in 2013.